# Append textarea values to existing array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea

I've a textarea consisting of 30 rows. I want to display the following array elements onto this textarea and add more elements to the textarea. After that, I want to append the added elements to the same array again. The array is given below:

var words = ['Starbucks', 'Coffee', 'Tea', 'Chai', 'Milk Tea', 'Mocha', 'Drink', 'Smoothy', 'Milk', 'Cappuccino'];

How can I accomplish this task? I'm in the learning process of Javascript and I need help with this part for my ongoing research project. If anybody can help me or give me valuable suggestions for accomplishing this, I'd be really grateful.

By the way, I'd tried using Array.join() method but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please show the code you tried, so we can help you understand why it didn't work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, if i understand what you need ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>words</title>

</head>
<body>

<label for="wordList">words</label>
<textarea id="wordList"></textarea>
<br />
<button onclick="loadFromArray();">Load from array</button>
<button onclick="saveToArray();">Save textarea to array</button>

    <script>
        var words = ['Starbucks', 'Coffee', 'Tea', 'Chai', 'Milk Tea', 'Mocha', 'Drink', 'Smoothy', 'Milk', 'Cappuccino'];
        console.log('initials words = %o', words);

        function loadFromArray() {
            document.getElementById('wordList').value = words.join('\n');
            console.log('loading words %o into textarea', words);
        }

        function saveToArray() {
            words = document.getElementById('wordList').value.split('\n');
            console.log('saving words %o from textarea', words);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```